# Remove Items From Table Output in Powershell

Tags: api, powershell

So, I have a powershell script pulling data from an API and returning it as a formatted table, though the final product will be a list. The problem is, when I print the table, I have some entries that I do not want in my final output. Here's how I'm building the table:

```
Write-Output $xml.pnet_message_history_packet_response.imessage | Format-Table -Property @{Label="form_id"; Expression={$_.formdata.form_id}}
, ... other fields... , 
@{Label="Test"; Expression={$_.formdata.im_field.field_number}}
```

And here's what the output looks like:

```
form_id        DriverName     TrailerNumber  TrailerHub     DefectFound    TractorDefect  Field7         TractorDefectD TractorRemarks MoreTractorDef Field11        Field13       TrailerDefect Test

-------        ----------     -------------  ----------     -----------    -------------  ------         -------------- -------------- -------------- -------        -------       ------------- ----
125413                                                                                                                                                                                           {5, 6, 12,...

92477                                                                                                                                                                                            1
125413                                                                                                                                                                                           {5, 6, 12,...

52768          regglseton     4022           0              Yes            Yes            Windows        Windows        driver side... No             Windows        Windows                     {2, 3, 4, ...
52768          Robert F       4035           111            No                                                                                                                                   {2, 3, 4, ...
53420          rs8                                                                                                                                                                            {8, 12, 13...
```

But what I want is to remove all the entries where the form_id is anything BUT 52768. I want to return the same data but only where form_id is 52768. To clarify further, I want the output like this:

```
form_id        DriverName     TrailerNumber  TrailerHub     DefectFound    TractorDefect  Field7         TractorDefectD TractorRemarks MoreTractorDef Field11        Field13       TrailerDefect Test

-------        ----------     -------------  ----------     -----------    -------------  ------         -------------- -------------- -------------- -------        -------       ------------- ----
52768          regglseton     4022           0              Yes            Yes            Windows        Windows        driver side... No             Windows        Windows                     {2, 3, 4, ...
52768          Robert F       4035           111            No                                                                                                                                   {2, 3, 4, ...
```

What is the best method to do this? Write the table to a text file and process the file line by line? I was hoping to avoid having to parse another string and was hoping to just narrow down the data printed in the script, but I will of course accept any answer that can help find the best simple solution!

Thank you!

Comment: Is a simple `Where-Object` possible to see if `form_id -eq "52768"`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for I just was having trouble figuring out where to put it. Seems silly but I couldn't find it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before piping to `Format-Table`, try filtering by form_id property using `Where-Object`:

```
Write-Output $xml.pnet_message_history_packet_response.imessage | Where-Object {$_.form_id -eq "52768"} | Format-Table
```

Or using the `in` operator:

```
Write-Output $xml.pnet_message_history_packet_response.imessage | Where-Object {$_.form_id -in "52768"} | Format-Table
```

This should remove the unwanted entries from the table.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you so much! Answer accepted.